# Corona SDK - LUA Setting attribute of an array works on simulator but not on device

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

This function reads a file line by line and sets global variables to the values read accordingly. However, the problem is that this code works on the simulator 100% fine however once compiled and run on the android device it stops working. Through the use of displaying text I have located the error to be on the line of code: "mapObject[i].x = sum". The attribute .x is of type real and I've already confirmed that sum, numerator and denominator are all numerical data types. The app crashes on the first run through of the loop containing "mapObject[i].x = sum" so i = 1. 1 is within range of the array. Any help is appreciated, I just can't get my head around this. Here is the function code:

```
-- Read map from file
local function loadmap(mapnum)
    local tempstring
    local numerator
    local denominator
    local sum
    local i

    local path = system.pathForFile( "maps/map" .. mapnum .. ".txt", system.ResourceDirectory)
    --Open the file
    local fh = io.open( path, "r" )

    if fh then
        -- read the lines of data systematically.
        mapName = fh:read( "*l" )
        mapNPCS = fh:read( "*l" )
        mapSpawnTimer = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
        mapSpawnMax = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
        mapSpawnMaxLocations = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
        mapObjectMax = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))

        for i = 1, mapObjectMax do
            tempstring = fh:read( "*l" )
            mapObject[i] = display.newImage("graphics/" .. tempstring .. ".png")

            -- Fractional mapping for all screen sizes
            denominator = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
            numerator = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
            sum = (display.contentWidth / denominator) * numerator
            mapObject[i].x = sum

            denominator = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
            numerator = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
            sum = (display.contentHeight / denominator) * numerator
            mapObject[i].y = sum

            mapObject[i].myName = "object"      

            physics.addBody(mapObject[i], "kinematic", {density = 10.0, friction = 0.0})
        end

        for i = 1, mapSpawnMaxLocations do
            mapSpawnX[i] = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
            mapSpawnY[i] = tonumber(fh:read( "*l" ))
        end

        io.close( fh )
    end
end
```

here is the global variables that come with the code:

```
-- Map Data Variables
local mapName
local mapNPCS
local mapSpawnTimer
local mapSpawnMax
local mapSpawnMaxLocations
local mapObjectMax
local mapObject = {}
local mapSpawnX = {}
local mapSpawnY = {}

-- Map Npc Spawning
local mapNPC = {}
local maxMapNPCS = 30
local npcsSpawned
local spawnTimer = 0
```

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try on physical device:

- If you use `sum = display.contentWidth` does it work?
- How about `sum =  100`?
- Could it be that the denominator is 0? (although that shouldn't cause a crash, just an error)
- Try replacing `mapObject[i].x = sum` by `mapObject[i].x = 100`, does it still crash?
- could it be that mapObject[i] is not a valid display object, say if the path in  `mapObject[i] = display.newImage("graphics/" .. tempstring .. ".png")` is not valid or if `tempstring` is empty? (although you'd think `display.newImage('graphics/.png')` should not cause any trouble)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that:

```
mapObject[i] = display.newImage("graphics/" .. tempstring .. ".png")
```

is producing a file name that's invalid on the device.  Device's are case sensitive, where as the simulator is not.